Next Js Master Detail Page
I am trying to create a master detail page layout using next js routing, similar like what we usually see on an email client app on desktop.

I have managed to achieve this behaviour using the folder structure like this.
- portal
  - customers
    - [id]
      page.tsx
    layout.tsx
    page.tsx
  layout.tsx

Customer Layout Code
export default function CustomersLayout(
  { children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    // within customer list 
    // it's just using <Link href='/portal/customers/{id}`></Link> to navigate
    // to the customers detail without using any state
    <MasterDetailLayout
    master={
      <CustomerList />
    }
    detail={children}
  ></MasterDetailLayout>);
}


However, when there are no customers selected I want to have an empty placeholder on the detail section.

But at the moment, I am just getting duplicated content for the master and detail in the route /customers. I am new to react and nextjs so any pointers on how to achieve the correct behaviour is greatly appreciated.


You did not provide your code examples, so if my understanding is correct, the default page should be in customers/page.tsx, and the customers/[id]/page.tsx should render based on the params clicked by the user. Try looking into these files.

@DaveLin yes! that got me in the right direction. Thanks!
